How can I capture the results of matrix jobs in a GitHub Actions workflow?
I wanted to capture the results of matrix jobs, but I couldn't find any relevant information in the GitHub Actions documentation. I reviewed the GitHub, needs, and matrix contexts, but found no solution.
Here’s how my workflow currently looks:
name:  Matrix workflow
on: workflow_dispatch
    
jobs:
  TEST-JOB:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        runner: [DEV, TEST, PROD]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest  
    steps:
      - name: Main step
        id: main-step
        run: echo "Dummy step"

  slack-post:
    needs: [TEST-JOB]
    if: ${{ !cancelled() }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        runner: [DEV, TEST, PROD]
    uses: .github/workflows/reusable-workflow.yml@main
    with:
      workflow_status: ${{ needs.TEST-JOB.result }}
    secrets: inherit

I have tried this workaround. Is there any better way to capture the result of the matrix jobs?

name:  Matrix workflow
on: workflow_dispatch
    
jobs:
  TEST-JOB:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        runner: [DEV, TEST, PROD]
    outputs:
      DEV_RESULT: ${{ steps.set-result.outputs.DEV_RESULT }}
      TEST_RESULT: ${{ steps.set-result.outputs.TEST_RESULT }}
      PROD_RESULT: ${{ steps.set-result.outputs.PROD_RESULT }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest  
    steps:
      - name: Main step
        id: main-step
        run: echo "Dummy step"

      - name: Set Result
        if: ${{ !cancelled() }}
        id: set-result
        run: |
          env="${{ matrix.runner }}"
          if [[ ${{ steps.main-step.outcome }} == 'success' ]]; then
            echo "${env}_RESULT=success" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
          else
            echo "${env}_RESULT=failure" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
          fi

  slack-post:
    needs: [TEST-JOB]
    if: ${{ !cancelled() }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        runner: [DEV, TEST, PROD]
    uses: .github/workflows/reusable-workflow.yml@main
    with:
      workflow_status: |
        "${{ (matrix.runner == 'DEV' && needs.TEST-JOB.outputs.DEV_RESULT) 
                  ||
            (matrix.runner == 'TEST' && needs.TEST-JOB.outputs.TEST_RESULT) 
                  ||
            (matrix.runner == 'PROD' && needs.TEST-JOB.outputs.PROD_RESULT) 
        }}"
    secrets: inherit


GitHub Actions workflows do not support collecting and referencing outcomes of individual matrix jobs. This is because a matrix is treated as a unit.
However, it is possible to produce an outcome for each job and then collect these outcomes into a JSON list of outcomes that can be then used as a dynamic matrix definition for a reporting job, exactly as you are trying to do in your question.
I have modified your workflow to achieve this. I commented out your private reusable workflow and simply replaced it with a simple run step that shows runner and its outcome in the logs. I also showed how your reusable workflow could be configured with two inputs.
In the workflow that follows, this line
jq -cn  --arg runner ${{ matrix.runner }} --arg outcome ${{ steps.main-step.outcome }} '$ARGS.named' > outcome

produces a JSON with two fields - runner and outcome.
-c tells jq to produce a compact one-line JSON output while -n indicates no input file. $ARGS.named creates a name-value JSON from the args.
This JSON is saved to a file that is uploaded as a workflow artifact.
All these JSON srtifacts are later downloaded and slurped into a single JSON list that is exported as an output and consumed as a matrix definition in the reporting job.
name:  Matrix workflow
on: workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  TEST-JOB:
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        runner: [DEV, TEST, PROD]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    continue-on-error: true
    steps:
      - name: Main step
        id: main-step
        run: |
          if [ ${{ matrix.runner }} = DEV ]; then
            # Simulate a failed run for DEV job.
            exit 1
          fi
      - if: ${{ !cancelled() }}
        run: |
          jq -cn  --arg runner ${{ matrix.runner }} --arg outcome ${{ steps.main-step.outcome }} '$ARGS.named' > outcome
      - if: ${{ !cancelled() }}
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: ${{ hashFiles('outcome') }}
          path: outcome

  collect:
    needs: TEST-JOB
    runs-on:  ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ !cancelled() }}
    outputs:
      outcomes: ${{ steps.collect.outputs.outcomes }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
      - id: collect
        run: |
          outcomes="$(cat */outcome | jq -c --slurp .)"
          echo outcomes=$outcomes >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT


  slack-post:
    needs: collect
    runs-on:  ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ !cancelled() }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        include: ${{ fromJSON(needs.collect.outputs.outcomes) }}
#    uses: .github/workflows/reusable-workflow.yml@main
#    with:
#      runner: ${{ matrix.runner }}
#      outcome: ${{ matrix.outcome }}
#    secrets: inherit
    steps:
      - run: echo ${{ matrix.runner }} ${{ matrix.outcome }}

